# Input field doesn't show the letters as I type even though the value attribute has a state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My input doesn't show the letters as I type even though I have set the value attribute and it is a controlled input. I have tried it on Stackbliz. My showText useState has empty string, If I change it to just black , I can see the input as I type but get another error saying " A component is changing an uncontrolled inout to controlled ....." and the input field is stuck making me unable to delete the text inside the input.

I am unable to figure out what is going wrong here.

Please check the link below.

Thanks!

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ensvyr?description=A%20create-react-app%20project%20based%20on%20react%20and%20react-dom&file=src%2FApp.js&title=React%20Starter

Comment: You need to include a minimal, reproducible example of the code you're having an issue with in your question, do **not** link to code hosted externally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `value={searchTerm}` from the `input` and everything should work as expected.
The hardcoded `value` overwrites what `setSearchTerm` does, everytime the component is reloaded

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I also have one more question , line 32 I am having a useEffect that runs handleSearch everytime the searchTerm changes. Do you think it is mandatory or i can remove that code?